# Why is my Object not filled

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to create a select object script in unity.

What it should do is when I hover over an object it colors red (and it does) and when I press "1" the GameObject's `targetHighlighted` will be filled with the object I am hovering over at that moment. In a `Debug.Log` this all works fine, `targetHighlighted`is filled.

When I press "1" however the `targetHighlighted` object is still left empty. It doesn't matter if I press it while hovering over the object or away from it.

My full code is much more extensive than this. But this section of code contains the problem, so I reduced it to this.

Can anyone explain to me how come when I press "1" the the `Debug.Log` doesn't show the `targetHighlighted` or `targetSelected`?

Basically why do the `mouseenter` and `mouseexit` log the right Object, but the `setTarget` function doesn't?

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TargetSelectionScript: MonoBehaviour {
    // Store the current selected gameobject
    GameObject targetHighlighted;
    Renderer rend;
    Color initialColor = Color.white;
    Color selectedColor = Color.red;
    public GameControllerScript gameController;

    void Start() {

    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1")) {
            SetTarget();
        }
    }

    void OnMouseEnter() {
        SelectTarget();
    }

    void OnMouseExit() {
        ClearTarget();
    }

    void SelectTarget() {

            RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();
            Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo);
            targetHighlighted = hitInfo.transform.gameObject;
            rend = targetHighlighted.GetComponent < Renderer > ();
            rend.material.color = selectedColor;
            Debug.Log("Highlighted target: " + targetHighlighted);

    }

    void ClearTarget() {
        Debug.Log(targetHighlighted);
    }

    void SetTarget() {
        Debug.Log(targetHighlighted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no key is registered under `"1"`

for this reason, you must resort to using the appropriate `KeyCode`,

```
if (GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    SetTarget();
```

Comment: Thanks for youre reply, but this isnt it. If i press 1 i do get a debug.log in the console, only not a value fortargetHighlighted

Comment: the gameobject the mouse enters and exits. since I only fill the value targetHighlighted and never clear it (only debug.log there), i expect the gameobject to be returned also when i press "1". A log entry is added, but with an empty gameobject instead of the gameobject i have set.

Comment: Wait so your saying that it debug logs `targetHighlighted` but its `null` ? So whats the problem? Is `targetHighlighted` not `null` before that method is ran ? And have you debugged it beforehand to make sure its not `null` bbeforehand ?

Comment: when i do a mouseenter the object i enters is shown in the log. like i expected. now the targetHighlighted is filled (i know that because the console shows me). If i after that press "1" the SetTarget function is called. Since i already filled the value of targetHighlighted, i expect the dublog.log show the same value when i press "1". But it doesnt. It gives a null. I can work around it, use a raycast to detect the gameobject the mouse is on. But when the mouse is off the object again, i dont know how to tell which object it was moved off. Thats why i would like to use mouseenter and mousexit

Comment: Try `Debug.Log(targetHighlighted.ToString());`, you see when you add a string to an object like you do in `SelectTarget()`, it automatically calls the `ToString()` function on the object behind the scenes. So right now, that is the only difference i see here

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
GameObject targetHighlighted;
Renderer rend;
Color initialColor = Color.white;
Color selectedColor = Color.red;
public GameControllerScript gameController;
[SerializeField]
private bool targetSelected = false;

void Start() {

}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("1") && this.targetSelected == true) {
        SetTarget();
    }
}

void OnMouseEnter() {
    SelectTarget();
}

void OnMouseExit() {
    ClearTarget();
}

void SelectTarget() {

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo);
        this.targetHighlighted = hitInfo.transform.gameObject;
        rend = this.targetHighlighted.GetComponent < Renderer > ();
        rend.material.color = selectedColor;
        Debug.Log("Highlighted target: " + targetHighlighted);
        this.targetSelected = true;

}

void ClearTarget() {
    Debug.Log(this.targetHighlighted);
}

void SetTarget() {
    Debug.Log(this.targetHighlighted);
}
```